# Is subclipse really needed in Flex when using SVN?

Tags: apache-flex, svn

I have a project both Flex and WWW and they are very closely connected. I want to put them both into into one SVN. I want to make revisions for changes that take place exactly both in flex and WWW at the same time.

My question is that do I have to stick to "subclipse" (it would desynchronise changes for flex and WWW in one revision)? Would be possible to make revisions using only my tortoiseSVN without subclipse?

What would be a best practice in this case?

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can use any method of updating / committing to your svn repository, but whichever way you choose.. (Eclipse based, go with Subversive or Subclipse, I recommend Subclipse, or TortoiseSVN or command line.) .. stick with it, I've had issues with Subclipse if I do svn operations with another client, although I'd hope those issues are no longer present in the current version.

There are some definite benefits to using an integrated scm client with Eclipse, the no. 1 reason being the integration itself, being able to use the checkout new project feature is also very nice.

At the end of the day it's up to you, or perhaps more importantly your team, it's certainly preferable to have your whole team using the same workflow and toolset.

In your specific case, it's probably not an issue to use Subclipse for your flex project and TortoiseSVN for your Web project, after all, many SVN repository setup's use a single repository for many different projects and basing everything on rev number isn't particularly relevant in these cases.

If a changeset affects the specific part of the tree in your working copy SVN is smart enough to figure that out, so just checkout the www and flex projects as separate working copies, it will work just fine.

Comment: OK, thank you for your quick reply. I'll not install Subclipse.

Comment: Just to note: @Slomojo may have had issues, but they shouldn't be common as the working copy format is the same.  The only issues I've ever had with using Subclipse, Tortoise and both the Windows and Cygwin command-line tools on the same checkout were that sometimes Subclipse doesn't pick up that you've committed using a different tool until you restart Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to indicate that Subclipse may have had issues in the past, but I'm talking about several years ago now.